# Is it possible to do bitwise operations on string flags within the class definition?

Tags: python, string, refactoring, enum-flags

I have created a custom class that extends `enum.Flag`:

```
from enum import Flag


class StrFlag(Flag):
    def __new__(cls, verbose):
        value = len(cls.__members__)
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = 2 ** value
        obj.verbose = verbose
        return obj


class Year(StrFlag):
    FIRST = 'First'
    SECOND = 'Second'
    THIRD = 'Third'
    FOURTH = 'Fourth'
    GRADUATE = 'Graduate'
    FACULTY = 'Faculty'
    OTHER = 'Some string with a space'
```

Now I want to add `UNDERGRADUATE`and `STUDENT` into the class. I know that the following code works:

```
Year.UNDERGRADUATE = Year.FIRST | Year.SECOND | Year.THIRD | Year.FOURTH
Year.STUDENT = Year.UNDERGRADUATE | Year.GRADUATE
```

but I want to put

```
UNDERGRADUATE = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD | FOURTH
STUDENT = UNDERGRADUATE | GRADUATE
```

within the class definition. However, Python won't let me do that because they are all strings. Is it possible to make the code cleaner?

Comment: try operator overloading, overload `__or__` to work as you want

Comment: @Dalvenjia Isn't that what `Flag` does to allow `Year.FIRST | Year.SECOND`?

Comment: The problem is that the assignments in the class definition occur *before* all the attributes are redefined to contain flag instances.

Comment: @Barmar You're right. `__or__ ` is already implemented in `Flag`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb16fb2cb8dca1fa1d67621c3175793eda7dbdc2/Lib/enum.py#L753

Comment: @Bartleby, yeah, sorry my bad I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can add new class attributes outside of the class definition. The following works just fine:

```
class Year(StrFlag):
    FIRST = 'First'
    SECOND = 'Second'
    THIRD = 'Third'
    FOURTH = 'Fourth'
    GRADUATE = 'Graduate'
    FACULTY = 'Faculty'
    OTHER = 'Some string with a space'
Year.UNDERGRADUATE = Year.FIRST | Year.SECOND | Year.THIRD | Year.FOURTH
Year.STUDENT = Year.UNDERGRADUATE | Year.GRADUATE
```

Comment: I know. I was just wondering if there is a way to put the last two statements inside the class definition, preferably concisely.